Can I manipulate channels of color attribute?
I want to create color attribute using this two:


to get attribute with R-Subsurface G-Pale B-Tan channels.
I suppose, I can do similar operation using texture baking (not sure if it'll work):

but I need to write it to color attribute. Can I do this somehow?

I can't understand your question.... where are these colors coming from? What is "it" that you need to write to color attribute?

Hello, @DanielMöller. I'm talking about vertex paint. The result of vertex paint is stored in color attributes (in object data, under uv maps tab).

So... you want to generate a third color attribute from two others?

@DanielMöller, yes.

You can do this in "Geometry Nodes" and later read it in a shader.

